# Filter strings dependent on comma separation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an table cell with the following value:

```
<td data-category="referencing">
    men,men-fashion,men-tops-sweatshirts,clothing,sweatshirts,sweatshirts-crewneck
</td>
```

I want to create a sort of filter which check there is less than 5 comma separations in the element, and if there is less than 5 add a class to the element.

What would be the approach to solve this task?

I am thinking an if statement which checks the text of the  element and checks if it includes five ','(commas) or not.

Comment: You can try with jQuery's `filter(function)`.. By the way, what have you tried and what went wrong with it?

Comment: use `.split` and check its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  You will have to inspect the element to see the result.

```js
$("td[data-category='referencing']").filter(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var arr = $this.text().split(",")
  if (arr.length >=5) {
    $this.addClass("commas");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td data-category="referencing">
    men,men-fashion,men-tops-sweatshirts,clothing,sweatshirts,sweatshirts-crewneck
</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and than check length

```js
let str  = `men,men-fashion,men-tops-sweatshirts,clothing,sweatshirts,sweatshirts-crewneck`

console.log(str.split(',').length > 5)

let str2 = 'hello,123'

console.log(str2.split(',').length > 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let string ='men,men-fashion,men-tops-sweatshirts,clothing,sweatshirts,sweatshirts-crewneck';
if(string.split(',').length-1 < 5){
    $(selector).addClass('class-name');
    console.log(string.split(',').length-1);
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

check length with:

```
'men,men-fashion,men-tops-sweatshirts,clothing,sweatshirts,sweatshirts-crewneck'.split(',').length;
```

Then it depends if you use JS or jQuery, but you need to select that element by some selector (ID if possible) and add class like this in condition if length is more then 5:

```
$( "#yourElementId" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cell_content = $('#whatever-you-need-to-select-this-cell').text();
var comas_count = cell_content.match(/,/g) || []).length
if(comas_count < 5){
    // add class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and check the length of the resulting array

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var texts = $("#td").html()
texts.split(',').length>5? $("#td").addClass('added'):false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td data-category="referencing" id="td">
    men,men-fashion,men-tops-sweatshirts,clothing,sweatshirts,sweatshirts-crewneck
</td>
</table>
```